# DJI: Getting exception on DJISDKManager registerApp method. Method addObserver must be called on the main thread

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I've integrated DJI Mobile SDK according to the guide and then even copied all the code from sample app(which works properly on my device), but in both cases I get the following exception when I call `DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp()` method. The lib is obfuscated, so I can't debug the error. The product is `Mavic 2 Enterprise`.

```
2020-12-22 12:31:11.382 2978-3031/com.example.package E/DJICrashHandler: uncaughtException 3
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-12-22 12:31:11.583 2978-3031/com.example.package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UrgentThreadPool#1
    Process: com.example.package, PID: 2978
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:317)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initParams()
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initSDKManager()
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.registerApp()
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.access$800()
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$6$1.onDownloadSuccess()
        at dji.internal.ghu.ghu.fdd()
        at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$6.run()
        at dji.sdksharedlib.gfd.koy.run()
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Looks like DJI SDK v4.14 is not compatible with the latest version (2.3.0) of androidx.lifecycle component.

Comment: Actually something was not working with ```koin-androidx-viewmodel``` dependency. When I changed it, the exception went away.

Comment: What did you end up changing? I also use koin and am getting this error with the same drone

Comment: @HaykKerobyan can you please specify what did you change in your dependencies? I have similar problem, but with Dagger and latest lifecycle components.